# Array Key as number

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I've an array $products:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2488
            [va] => 1526
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19512
            [va] => 286
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [va] => 286
        )
);
```

Now I've to build a second key => value array where:

```
key => [va]
value => frequency of key in the first array
```

So the output will be:

```
array(1526 => 1, 286 => 2)
```

I've tried:

```
$test = array();

foreach($products as $product) {
    $va = $product['va'];
    $test["$va"]++;
}
```

This way I receive a lot of "undefined offset", how can I use a number as associative array key?

Comment: paste your desire output.

Comment: You first have to define a value before you can increment it. Without that your line `$test["$va"]++;` tries to increment a non existing value with each execution.

Comment: i've pasted my desired output, what about downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first have to define a value before you can increment it. Without that your line $test["$va"]++; tries to increment a non existing value with each execution. Have a try with this modified approach:

```
<?php

$products = [
    [ 'id' => 2488, 'va' => 1526 ],
    [ 'id' => 19510, 'va' => 286 ],
    [ 'id' => 19511, 'va' => 286 ],
    [ 'id' => 19512, 'va' => 286 ],
];

$test = [];
foreach($products as $product) {
    $va = $product['va'];
    $test[$va] = isset($test[$va]) ? ++$test[$va] : 1;
}

var_dump($test);
```

The output obviously is:

```
array(2) {
  [1526] =>
  int(1)
  [286] =>
  int(3)
}
```

Comment: I've tried adding a new product with va "286" and the output for that key is still 1. I just noticed that your code works using "+ 1" and not "++", wondering why...

Comment: Your code not working for this 
$products = [
    0 => [ 'id' => 2488, 'va' => 1526 ],
    1 => [ 'id' => 19512, 'va' => 286 ],
 2 => [ 'id' => 19562, 'va' => 286 ]
];

Comment: @Jumpa Sorry, fixed the obvious issue. My bad. You obviously need to pre-incement before the assignment.

Comment: No problem, just accepted your answer, +1 for pre-increment.

Answer (score 1):

"One-line" solution using `array_column` and `array_count_values` functions:

```
// $products is your initial array
$va_count = array_count_values(array_column($products, 'va'));

print_r($va_count);
```

The output:

```
(
    [1526] => 1
    [286] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if keys is exists or not, if not then set value as 1 , Use like below

```
$test = array();

foreach($products as $product) {
    $va = $product['va'];
    if(isset($test["$va"]))
    {
        $test["$va"]++;
    }
    else
    {
      $test["$va"]=1;
    }
}
```